# LINQ On DataTables With Multiple Conditions

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

This query just doesnt seem to be very happy.  Any ideas anyone?

```
var results = from a in previousQuery
              join b in dtCounties.AsEnumerable()
              on new { a.CountyCode, a.StateCode } equals new { 
                  b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE"),
                  b.Field<string>("StateCode") 
              }
              where b.Field<bool>("TrueOrFalse") == true
              select new
              {
                  CountyCode = a.CountyCode,
                  TrueOrFalse= b.Field<bool>("TrueOrFalse"),
                  Sum= a.Sum
              };
```

The error I get is

> "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."

for the 2 columns in the right hand side of the join (ie  `b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE")` and `b.Field<string>("StateCode")`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a C# syntax issue, not LINQ itself. Consider the following:

```
var a = new { "1" };     // Error
var a = new { a = "1" }; // OK
```

Just to clarify, here is the result of the above:

```
on new { cc = a.CountyCode, sc = a.StateCode }
    equals new { cc = b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE"),
                 sc = b.Field<string>("StateCode") }
```

Comment: Agree. I think problem here new { b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE") ,b.Field<string>("StateCode") }, set naming: new { field1 = b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE") , field2 = b.Field<string>("StateCode") }

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the results of the field operator to named properties.

Try this:

```
var results= from a in previousQuery
             join b in dtCounties.AsEnumerable()
             on new { CountryCode = a.CountyCode, StateCode = a.StateCode } 
             equals new 
                    { CountryCode = b.Field<string>("COUNTYCODE") ,
                      StateCode = b.Field<string>("StateCode") }
             where b.Field<bool>("TrueOrFalse") == true
             select new
             {
                    CountyCode = a.CountyCode,
                    TrueOrFalse= b.Field<bool>("TrueOrFalse"),
                    Sum= a.Sum
             };
```

Comment: That will not work, due to the phrase `new { a.CountyCode, a.StateCode }`, see my answer